# GSON how to deserialize an object with a generic value type that I don't know

Tags: java, json, rest, deserialization

So I have a MyCustomObject with the following format:

```
public class MyCustomObject<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<MyCustomObject<T>> {
    private String id;
    private T value;

    ~~getters
    ~~setters
}
```

I have a REST endpoint that needs to deserialize this JSON object and put it back into a MyCustomObject. I don't care what type T is since the rest of my code handles it as long as it implements Comparable. Here is my controller code:

```
  @PostMapping("/myEndpoint")
  public <T extends Comparable<T>> ResponseEntity<Integer> balancingPost(@RequestBody MyCustomObject<T> mco) {...}
```

My code is throwing an exception here when I try to hit this endpoint with a ControlPoint passed in via the body:

*MyCustomObject["value"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Comparable: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information*

So is there a way for me to get away without specifying the concrete type of T here? I want to keep my code as generic as possible.

Comment: I would doubt it.  It has to know what `T` is to deserialize it in the first place.

Comment: @LouisWasserman So is there a way to pass the type in to my controller endpoint? The consumer will know the type but it is getting lost after calling my REST service.